# Why might an EXIF DateTimeOriginal be later than photo capture?

Tags: metadata, exiftool

As it says in the title, assuming no hacking/malicious editing of EXIF. In my case DateTimeDigitized and DateTimeOriginal are the same if that makes any difference to the potential reasons.

Comment: Hard to tell without more info, which camera and which timezone?

Comment: Actually not sure, do certain cameras list it as time of upload? Timezone is GMT both of photo and test (on computer using ImageMagick)

Comment: Was the clock on the camera accurate?  What do you mean by "photo capture"?  What are you using to view the photo capture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest explanation would be that the time and/or date set inside the camera was incorrect at the moment the photo was captured.

It's pretty easy to set the camera to a date or time in the future, take a photo, and then set the date/time back to the correct setting for one's locale. The EXIF info is static. It won't be affected by any changes made to the camera's date/time *after* the image was captured. It is recorded data that will still reflect the date/time imprinted at the time of capture.

If your camera was set to the local time zone where you live and you got on a plane and flew halfway around the world without changing the camera's clock to the new locale, then the date/time stamp on the photo would be twelve hours off one way or the other, depending on both locations' position relative to the international date line.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @michael c. Would any photo editing software accidentally change the EXIF?

Comment: Though it is perhaps conceivable that one might accidentally change the EXIF info when using photo editing software, it's very highly unlikely. For the app to do it without any user input would mean the programmer who created the app instructed the app to make such changes without input from the user. There are other explanations that would be far more likely. Perhaps one made a mistake when using an EXIF editor to edit other fields, for instance. You *really* need to provide more specific info if you expect an answer that applies to your specific situation. "20 questions" is not a fun game.